# How do i make center email content is visible

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create HTML email page where there should be fixed header,center and footer. I am facing difficulty to see center content to make center content is visible i have added so much br tag after navbar div. how do avoid this. How do i reduce distance between support.html line to All rights reserved How do i reduce header and footer height.

```css
 * {
            font-family: 'Ubuntu';
   font-size: 18px;
        }
        
        .footer {
            position: fixed;
            left: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            width: 100%;
            background-color: #3498DB;
            color: white;
            text-align: center;
        }
        
        .flex-container {
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
        }
        
        p {
            padding: 10px;
        }
        
        img {
            padding-right: 5px;
        }
        
        .navbar {
            position: fixed;
            right: 0;
            top: 0;
            width: 100%;
            background-color: #3498DB;
            color: white;
            text-align: center;
        }
```

```html
 <div class="navbar"> 
 <h1><span><img width="30" height="30" src="data:image/png;base64,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" alt="Error"></span></h1>   
   <p> A abcd abcde abcdabcd abc abcde abcdefgh </p>
   </div>
   <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
   <h2 style="text-align: center;">Invitation to join Project ((ProjectName))</h2><br>    
   
   ((InviterFirstName)) ((InviterLastName)) has invited you as ((ProjectRole)) to the following project.<br>
   Project Name: ((ProjectName))<br>
   Project Number: ((ProjectNumber))<br><br><br>

   Team HTML

   <div class="footer">

<div class="flex-container">
<p style="text-align:left;"><span><img width="30" height="30" src="data:image/png;base64,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" alt="Error"></span><a href="mailto:support@html.com" style="color:white;">support@html.com</a></p> 
   <p style="text-align:right;"><span><img width="30" height="30" src="data:image/png;base64,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" alt="Error"></span>175B ABC ABCD AB 95138</p> 
</div>
   
   <p>© 2020 All rights reserved</p>

   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**change `z-index:`on the navbar**, **this only happens when screeens are really cropped**. the best way to fix this would be to set`html  { min-height: 100vh; }` but if you dont want to do that, changing z-index on the footer would be the best option

**Footer is now gray to better display what happens**

```css
* {
           font-family: 'Ubuntu';
     font-size: 18px;
       }

       .footer {
           position: fixed;
           left: 0;
           bottom: 0;
           width: 100%;
           background-color: #3498DB;
           background: #333;
           color: white;
           text-align: center;
       }

       .flex-container {
           display: flex;
           align-items: center;
           justify-content: center;
       }

       p {
           padding: 10px;
       }

       img {
          padding-right: 5px;
       }

       .navbar {
           position: fixed;
           right: 0;
           top: 0;
           width: 100%;
           background-color: #3498DB;
           color: white;
           text-align: center;
           z-index: 5;
       }
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
        <h1><span><img  src="https://dvlc9qcftewvt.cloudfront.net/assets/images/Group3819.png" alt="Error"></span></h1>
        <p> A real cloud platform for steel industry </p>
    </div>

    <h2 style="text-align: center;">Invitation to join Project ((ProjectName))</h2>
    <br> ((InviterFirstName)) ((InviterLastName)) has invited you as ((ProjectRole)) to the following project.
    <br> Project Name: ((ProjectName))
    <br> Project Number: ((ProjectNumber))
    <br>
    <br>
    <br> Team HTML

    <div class="footer">
        <div class="flex-container">
            <p style="text-align:left;"><span><img width="30" height="30" src="https://dvlc9qcftewvt.cloudfront.net/assets/images/slicing/email.png" alt="Error"></span><a href="mailto:support@virtuele.us" style="color:white;">support@virtuele.us</a></p>
            <p style="text-align:right;"><span><img width="30" height="30" src="https://dvlc9qcftewvt.cloudfront.net/assets/images/slicing/location.png" alt="Error"></span>175B San Jose CA 95138</p>
        </div>
        <p>© 2020 All rights reserved</p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid br added extra div "section" and add margin 120px. You do not need to put padding 10px to tag "p".
PS: the snipet does not look nice because of fixed footer and header. If you commit the position it will be nicer.

```css
* {
            font-family: 'Ubuntu';
         font-size: 18px;
            margin:0;
        }
        
        .footer {
            position: fixed;
            left: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            width: 100%;
            background-color: #3498DB;
            color: white;
            text-align: center;
        }
        
        .flex-container {
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
        }
        
       p {
            padding: 5px;
        }
        
        img {
            padding-right: 10px;
        }
        
        .navbar {
            position: fixed;
            right: 0;
            top: 0;
            width: 100%;
            background-color: #3498DB;
            color: white;
            text-align: center;
        }

.section{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  margin:120px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar"> 
 <h1><span><img width="30" height="30" src="data:image/png;base64,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" alt="Error"></span></h1>   
   <p> A abcd abcde abcdabcd abc abcde abcdefgh </p>
   </div>
   <div class="section">
   <h2 style="text-align: center;">Invitation to join Project ((ProjectName))</h2>
     
     <p>((InviterFirstName)) ((InviterLastName)) has invited you as ((ProjectRole)) to the following project.</p>  
   <p>Project Name: ((ProjectName))</p>
   <P>Project Number: ((ProjectNumber))</p>
   <p>Team HTML</p>
  </div>

   <div class="footer">

<div class="flex-container">
<p style="text-align:left;"><span><img width="30" height="30" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAOEAAADhCAMAAAAJbSJIAAAAdVBMVEX///8AAABLS0ujo6OWlpba2trQ0ND8/Pz39/fz8/P4+PhPT0/s7OzU1NQ7Ozvj4+OysrLExMRCQkISEhJpaWkmJiaDg4M1NTV7e3sZGRlZWVlgYGC9vb0aGhqIiIgqKiqbm5siIiJ1dXVoaGheXl6Ojo6pqamU9iTBAAAEaklEQVR4nO3c61riMBSF4XDQIooKHkB0EHX0/i9xZMQhK80JaPbO+Kzv30iH9FVoS9tgDGOMMcYYY4wxxhhjjDHGGGOMMcYYY4wxxhhjjDHGGGPsx/YxrKePIsJZr55mRYR9bZZVn0IKKVSPQgop3DY9kepqoCPsnRUZx9NE6W8oRmwBBd+HIsQ2UHJLMyoyFHTiGVZQeFOc6AOK7i1KE73A4sJbe7CHcZHRtvmBxYVmaY/2qyARgUM5oTm3B35pioxnXODKCApliC5QVIjbnbsiRATeG2EhEp8LjHfVAgoL8dxb90QPUFqIxHnHo/mA4kJzWY6IwMX2p+JCJF52OJYfqCAsRQwANYRmbq9KV+faEfi6e0BDWIIYBOoIzXPXxDBQSdgA8fihL8JAJaFp7rokxoBaQtO82Ct1ftQgCLx1HtUSmuZXV8Q4UE9oxg/2ii0PHiIBVBR2REwBNYVmdGOv3O+DBkDgm2cJTaEZweo9HvD8aaCu0JwdScwAKgsdon8Vw2X9gpSFzkp6NhSR8l4B2sIjiPg/gxsqdWH8kCtSJrAC4YFEBEb2phUIDyJmA6sQOsRFbNFtuCeNHg9VIdybiEdD8QO+OoT+M53BEJj4XFKJcC/iXsBqhA5xFVlyP2A9wmzieD9gRUKH+B5YCj9VZqx1RUKzyCCO4eRHzrNWJHzvYUPPMnh2J+vwoB7hsOfWJuIZuk3pfWc1wjaw11s7y7SB6X1nNcK1B+gSfcD4jmVTJUL3XtDvBtYyeJ58V2iru60O4UcAaBNDQP8maVcVwmtYYeR+E0d4MQeWWceevAYhAifmFP7dn44+jwbwfXrpHB4MIs9egfAJVvb08ydIbLe5NI63BkXmpekL20BjplHg1x0cSLwOPr+6EDFT7099QPdG5yBRW+gHxoi7e3DwxfwUGEFZGF5JfPH6gJlEXWFsFf1EvIsq9AqwUxXG30m+m5ndc+IZRE1halPR4AdGL8G3JcYUhRl7tIt7a4mZd3OZJOoJERg8KpkMFstZ/231FJpq4x4RuakJ8bBrfcQYeBx74j6sJURg/NNBqjhRSdgl0P10eYUP6gjxOkXiI2xG+MkDiSpCBKZOQ+SEZ3mAqCFEYPJUUlZ4KvLCekRBiBc3c64W5rQKEeWFCMy/bp/qHp53t/cUF+LV2+6A7kWBf0RpIV452u/+mVSvQPyexSksbODK0b73QKWCWZw32ymOskI8a33IrXrx3uynf/iaHCcqxBvYD79pNtyjPcDXFEdRYXGgwbm4fyfHSQphIslxN6+HA+LmnIegEOY7lRluE8zFnUsKYeZhmW8Wc8fsbU6PiwmXOG7J4He5G1fyOxXKAp33g4aw68mx7ea+YeWEJeZwuz17xhUTlpmH7+S7YCwlLPd1EZDnrgYhochfcFP7ryj1XV+TU5kmretz/L42CinUj0IKKdSvjPDnf5/39aCewjeGMcYYY4wxxhhjjDHGGGOMMcYYY4wxxhhjjDHGGGOMMcb++/4A3qE/10C+aHIAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" alt="Error"></span><a href="mailto:support@html.com" style="color:white;">support@html.com</a></p> 
   <p style="text-align:right;"><span><img width="30" height="30" src="data:image/png;base64,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" alt="Error"></span>175B ABC ABCD AB 95138</p> 
</div>
   
   <p>© 2020 All rights reserved</p>

   </div>
```

Upd: I've changed snipet with *{margin:0}

Comment: is it possible to  reduce space between below two elements

Element 1

<div class="flex-container">
</div

Element 2
<p>© 2020 All rights reserved</p>

Comment: the best way to do it just add  * { margin:0; } and than you can use your p{padding>10px}

Comment: In this case all default setting will change and it's easy to work with styles. You can read more about normalize.css

Answer (score -1):

You've used `fixed` positioning on the `navbar` element. An element with fixed positioning is not considered to be in the flow of the document. One fix would be to wrap the centre content in a `div` with a top margin of however tall the navbar is.